# restricting a vector field to an open set

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I have a vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ on a manifold $M$ and an open set $U$ of $M$. What does it mean to restrict $X$ to $U$? How do we define the following?

$$X\vert_U:C^\infty(U)\rightarrow C^\infty(U)$$

Comment: I guess  $M$  is a smooth manifold, right?

Comment: yes exactly. I'll edit that

Comment: Well if $f$ is a smooth function on $M$ and $m$ any point in $M$, then $X(f)(m)$ only depend on the germ of $f$ at $m$. Therefore you can define $X_U(h)(m)$ to be the $X(g)(m)$ for any $g\in C^\infty(M)$ such that $g=h$ on a sufficiently small neighborhood of $m$. This does not depend on $g$.

Comment: True I had forgotten that fact thanks

Comment: And such a $g$ exists thanks to the "bump" function?

Comment: For instance, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a  vector field over a smooth manifold $M$ is a section of the tangent bundle $TM$. So it is a map
$$
X : M \to TM
$$
such that for every $p \in M$ it holds $X(p) \in T_pM$. 
Restricting $X$ to $U$ means nothing else but restricting the domain of $X$, as you would do in general when you consider the restriction of a function.

Comment: You would have to show that $X_U(p)$ which you define as $X(p)$ is indeed in $T_pU$ for $X_U$ to be a vector field. And that works with the definition/remark of @A.Rod

Comment: Sure. But in principle you can always consider the restriction $X_{|U} : U \to TM$ for any subset $U \subset M$. When $U$ is open, it is a manifold. And because of @A.Rod's remark, you have that $X_{|U}$ is actually a section of the tangent bundle $TU$.

Comment: Ok. Agreed. A linked question: If $L$ is a sub manifold of $M$ (i.e. an injective immersion), we don't necessarily have that $L$ is open in $M$ so could not say that the restriction of $X$ to $\iota(L)$ would be a vector field?

Comment: First, examine the case of a hyperplane (or any subvector space for that matter) in a vector space. This is a submaniflod and certainly not open.
Moreover, if you restrict a vector field on a vector space (which is simply a smooth function $V\to V$) to a subvector space... there no reason for it to be tangent to the subvector space.

Comment: can the same definition as you put in your first remark work if my submanifold is actually a leaf of a distribution? I don't see that we would be able to "extend" a function defined on $\iota(L)$ to the whole of $M$.

Comment: The problem is not to extend the function (which is possible, by the tubular neighborhood theorem for instance), it is to make sure that the definition does not depend on the choices. And it will be. Then again consider a basic exemple, such as $\{y=0\}$ lying in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which is as nice a submanifold as can be) and the constant vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $(0,1)$, or if you prefer $\partial_y$. Then the only reasonable way to "restrict" your vector field is to... send it to 0.

Comment: @A.Rod If you endow your ambient manifold with a Riemannian metric, and if your submanifold has codimension 1, then the canonical way to restrict your vector field is to take the "tangential" part.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "restriction"... but of course you can do that since the riemannian metric allows you to cannonically split the exact sequences of bundle (in this case $0\to TL \to i^*TM\to Q\to 0$. The Riemann metric gives you a projection map $i^*TM\to TL$ which on global section gives you the "tangential restriction". This works in any codimension... but I doubt that what the OP had in mind?

Comment: @A.Rod Yes, I agree. I  wouldn't call it "restriction" either.. :D