# restricting a vector field to a leaf

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds

I have a vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$ equipped with a distribution $\cal{D}$ such that $X_p\in{\cal{D}}_p$ for all $p\in M$.

What does it mean to restrict $X$ to a leaf $L$?

Reminder: a leaf is an injective immersion tangent to the distribution. i.e. $\iota:L\rightarrow M$ is injective and $\iota_{*p}$ is injective for all $p\in M$ and $\iota_{*p}(T_pL) = {\cal{D}}_{\iota(p)}$ for all $p\in M$

The question is then what is the definition of $X\vert_L$? (ps: I need it to bee a vector field on $L$)

My idea following [restricting a vector field to an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599562/restricting-a-vector-field-to-an-open-set?noredirect=1#comment5367741_2599562) was to define as follows

$$X\vert_L:C^\infty(L)\rightarrow C^\infty(L):f\mapsto X(f'')$$

where $f'$ is the function that $f$ defines on $\iota(L)$ and $f''\in C^\infty(M)$ which is equal to $f'$ on $\iota(L)$.

A few worries:

1. Not sure such an $f''$ exists
2. Not sure that this definition is independent of the choice of $f''$ (indeed, $\iota(L)$ is not necessarily open in $M$.

Comment: I'm assuming $D$ and $X$ are related? Do you look at the integral submanifolds associated to vector field, in other words $D(x)=\mathbb{R} X(x)$ (assuming you work over the real numbers)?

Comment: sorry, yes $X$ is a section of $\cal{D}$ i.e. $X_p\in {\cal{D}}_p$ for all $p\in M$.

Comment: Well in the case it is automatic! The very existence of $L$ is tantamount to the fact the some vector field on $L$ will be mapped to your $X$ by the (differential) of the inclusion.

Comment: Ok but what vector field is it that will be sent to $X$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The vector field $X$ is already a vector field on $L$. Of course you could give it another name. 
Like yesterday, I invite you to look at the simple case of a line in a plane.

Comment: Ok. I'll write something down as an answer. I know this is all very trivial but I like to write things down as properly as I can the first time I go through them.

Answer (score 1):

$X:M\rightarrow TM$.

If I can define $X^{\iota(L)} := X\vert_{\iota(L)}:\iota(L)\rightarrow TM$ and observe that actually $X_{\iota(L)} \in T_{\iota(l)}\iota(L)$, then I can define $X^L:L\rightarrow TL:p\mapsto X_{\iota(p)}$ (since $T_lL\cong T_{\iota(l)}\iota(L)$)

but $X_{\iota(l)}\in{\cal{D}}_{\iota(l)} = \iota_{*l}T_lL = T_{\iota(l)}\iota(L)$

So we have our result